# Rails routes config thinks action method is an object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes, rails-routing

I'm developing rails application and encountered such problem.

I have `movies_controller.rb`, where I have these actions and routes defined:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
            movies GET    /movies(.:format)             movies#index
                   POST   /movies(.:format)             movies#create
         new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)         movies#new
        edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)    movies#edit
             movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)         movies#show
                   PATCH  /movies/:id(.:format)         movies#update
                   PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)         movies#update
                   DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)         movies#destroy
              root GET    /                             redirect(301, /movies)
movies_by_director GET    /movies/by_director(.:format) movies#by_director
```

But when I try to go to `/movies/by_director?director="something"`, rails think, that I'm navigating to `movies#show` action with parameter `:id = by_director`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes are matched in the order they are specified so make sure the route for "by_director" is defined **above** the resource routes for movies.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
get '/movies/by_director' => 'movies#by_director'
resources :movies
```

Comment: It does in deed. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in one here:

1. The default pattern matching for `:id` is loose enough that `by_director` is interpreted as an `:id`.
2. Routes are matched in order and `GET /movies/:id` appears before `GET 
   /movies/by_director`.

You can manually define `GET /movies/by_director` before your `resources :movie` as [infused suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40249470/479863) or you could add a constraint to narrow what `:id`s look like:

```
resources :movies, constraints: { id: /\d+/ } do
  #...
end
```

Manually ordering the routes is fine if there's just one or two of them to deal with, constraining `:id` is (IMO) cleaner and less error prone.